# Understanding a proof of Lusin. Question about measure of the set discontinuity point of a step function defined on finite measurable sets.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I'm reading a proof and I don't understand the red part.

I think that if $f_n$ is a step function, then the set of points in which $f_n$ is discontinuous is countable, in particular has $0$ lebesgue measure. Therefore I can find a measurable set $E_n$ such that $m(E_n)=0$ and $f_n$ is continuous in $E-E_n$. Tell me why I'm wrong =( . Obviously in this case $m(E_n)< \frac{1}{2^n}$ too. But I don't think that the book does not considered what I said. (That's why I think that I'm wrong).

[image]